# Display: table-cell, contents and padding

Tags: html, css

I have a very straightforward HTML page that displays content in two columns. To format the columns I'm using `<div>` as the outer container (display: table-row) and two inner `<div>` as the actual columns (display: table-cell). One of these columns has a padding at the top. The markup looks like the following - extra markup and styles omitted for clarity:

```
<style>
.row { display: table-row }
.cell { display: table-cell; border: 1px solid black; width: 150px }
.content { background-color: yellow }
</style>

<div class="row">
   <div class="cell">
      <div class="content">Some content; this is not padded.</div>
   </div>

    <div class="cell">
        <div class="content">More content; padded at the top.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

I'm getting this:

[image]

---

But I expected this:

[image]

---

The behavior is the same whether the `padding-top` is applied to the cell or the content. Am I missing anything? Thanks.

Comment: Could we have some HTML code?

Comment: Yes, up there after the first paragraph!

Comment: Haha, for some reason the first time I saw this I thought of Myles Gray. Look who's here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve your two desired results just by using `padding` and `margin` on your div with the class `content`. Remember, padding will contribute to the overall width and height of an object, so that will extend the background color.

First screen shot:

```
<div class="content" style="margin-top: 10px">More content; padded at the top.</div>
```

Second screen shot:

```
<div class="content" style="padding-top: 10px">More content; padded at the top.</div>
```

Comment: Well, `margin` didn't do the trick, and `padding` is exactly what I'm using to produce the yellow (_undesired_) rendering! For clarity, I'm including some details in the screen shot. Thanks!

Comment: I'm giving the `margin` to the `content` div. Check out the working example: http://jsfiddle.net/4GYn9/

Comment: Whoops -- I myself had "mistakenly" left `vertical-align` in the .cell class and that alone solves it all. I've updated the example in jsFiddle; check it out. I was tinkering with `vertical-align` but didn't pay attention as I was busy preparing this question... thanks anyway!

Comment: @humberto your solution works pls make it an answer and accept it :P Im faving this I spent so much time with this problem

Comment: Add `.cell { vertical-align: top; }` to this answer and it is correct.