# css to work with dynamic 1, 2, 3 column layout based on if column exist with 1 set of rules

Tags: css, xhtml, xhtml-1.0-strict

## Note:

In some situations elements with `display:table-cell;` have space at the top that is not padding, or margin and `border-collapse:collapse;` doesn't fix it either. You need to also use `vertical-align:text-top;`. [Another users question on the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995762/display-table-cell-contents-and-padding).

## Original question

I create my template files with php and have been using 3 different sets of css rules for the columns depending on if there is 1, 2 or 3 columns. Im wondering if I can get 1 set of rules to work.

glimpse of the php idea

```
if($this->_data['left']!=NULL)
    echo "<div id='left'>{$this->left}</div>";
if($this->_data['right']!=NULL)
    echo "<div id='right'>{$this->right}</div>";
echo "<div id='content'>{$this->main}</div>";
```

`#left` and `#right` would be fixed width and to the left and right. The `#main` would be in center and use up the rest of the `#wrappers` width. so if there wasnt a `#right` the `#main` would fill the space where `#right` would have been.

```
<!-- 3 column -->
<div id='container'>
    <div id='left'></div>
    <div id='main'></div>
    <div id='right'></div>
</div>

<!-- 2 column -->
<div id='container'>
    <div id='left'></div>
    <div id='main'></div>
</div>
<!-- or -->
<div id='container'>
    <div id='main'></div>
    <div id='right'></div>
</div>

<!-- 1 column -->
<div id='container'>
    <div id='main'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use display:table property for this. Write like this:

```
#container{
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}
#container > div{
    display:table-cell;
    height:50px;
}
#left, #right{
    width:100px;
    background:red;
}
#right{
    background:green;
}
#main{
    background:blue;
}
```

Check  this http://jsfiddle.net/HXaPR/

Comment: thanks. I forgot all about the display properties other than block, inline and of course inline-block. It seems like it isnt supported by IE7 which is why I didnt use it then. But according to the w3c IE7 is now down to ~2.7% and still on the decline so Ill go ahead and use it :)